# Client server java application: send large file using SOAP and AXIS2

Tags: java, performance, soap, apache-axis, java2wsdl

I have to send a millions of data over the network using Soap Web Services (java2wsdl) between java client/server. So I tried to serialize objects into a file and then send it to server.

But the problem is that serialization generates a very large file that causes memory problems in java application.

Since the file is very big I tried to split this file into small ones. The problem is that I must send n files between the client and the server, which will consume a lot of time while the objectif is to optimize the processing time.

Do you have any suggestions to optimize the processing time and ensuring no "out of memory"?

Answer (score 0):

Web services arent designed primarily as a large file transfer mechanism. For that specific file transfer protocols will do a better job, like dealing with partial recovery, error recovery etc.

[Try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14454147/1958134)